# Calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty}\Big(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x^2+2)^n}dx\Big)^{1/n}$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lebesgue-integral

> Calculate $$\lim_{n \to \infty}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{e^{-x^2}}{(x^2+2)^n}dx\right)^{1/n}$$

I thought I was supposed to use Dominated Convergence Theorem but I believe I cannot use it here. Then I tried to use the definition of $p$-norm but I realized I need X to have finite measure to apply the convergence of $p$-norm to $\infty$-norm.

Comment: Hint: use $2\le x^2+2\le2e^{x^2/2}$. You should find the limit is $\frac12$.

Comment: Generally if $f\ge 0$ is continuous and bounded then the limit of $$\left (\int\limits f(x)^ne^{-x^2}\,dx\right)^{1/n}$$ is equal $\sup f(x).$ The measure $d\mu(x)=e^{-x^2}\,dx$ is finite.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc Is there a name for this result?

Comment: @Math1000 Not my knowledge. The proof is straightforward by estimating from above by $\|f\|_\infty \mu (\mathbb{R})^{1/n}$ and from below by $$(\|f\|_\infty-\delta) \mu \{x\,:\,|f(x)|\ge \|f\|_\infty -\delta\}^{1/n}$$ for any fixed $\delta >0$

Comment: I suppose you mean something aside from $\mu(\mathbb R)^{1/n}$? Since of course that quantity is infinite?